# MySQL or Oracle?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

As I know these two databases are the most popular and the best, but which one is the best? And what are the benefits to use one or other? Currently I use `MySQL` and I don't really have any experiences with `Oracle`, but I want to know what's the best choice and why?

I mean how fast they are, what kind of features they have, how easy is to use them with php, and so one, you know better :)

Some real examples:

1. 1.000.000 users come to my
   website, they visit 100 pages every day and each
   page is 1mb's , now which
   on is the faster?
2. I run a query on the database to
   search for 10.000 users, now which
   one is faster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL vs. SQL Server vs. Oracle...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913547/mysql-vs-sql-server-vs-oracle)

Comment: possible duplicate of When to choose Oracle over MySQL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788854/when-to-choose-oracle-over-mysql

Comment: Really, you _know_ that, do you? So you've used dBase, ADABAS, FileMaker, Paradox, Access, SQLServer, Informix, PostgreSQL, SQLite, DB2, Cloudscape, Derby, NoSQL databases, non-relational ones such as IMS, Codebase, and others, then come to that conclusion. That's quite an achievement.

Comment: I don't see how this won't get closed as subjective and argumentative. It really is never a good idea to ask what is "best" on SO unless you qualify it with "given these requirements"

Comment: Guys, I'ts a bad question or what? I just want to know which one should I use, and why.

Comment: If you're using MySQL and it's not hideously broken, stick with it. There's no point in changing for the sake of change. I could also have the best development system possible if I wanted to spend $50K but there's nothing _wrong_ with my current $3K one - well, that and the fact my wife would take out a contract on me :-)

Comment: If I have a good reason to change I will, but I want to know if it exits a reason or not :)

Comment: @Cirk, if _you_ don't have a reason to change, then there _is_ no reason for you to change. Us telling you why MySQL should be replaced should have no effect on you. Do you buy all those crappy exercise things marketed on late-night TV just because someone told you to? :-) FWIW, I won't use Oracle because it can't tell the difference between NULL and an empty string. But then, I'm a DB2 man.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Your wife would take out a contract on you with what money? You spent it all!

Comment: Asking for the differences between MySQL and Oracle is one thing, asking which is "best" is another. Neither is best; they both have their ups and downs. Either narrow it down with criteria or simply ask for practical differences between them.

Comment: @BalusC: I have trouble pronouncing PostgreSQL, so cannot in good conscience recommend it as the **best** database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, when you add in "how easy to use with PHP," I'm going to have to go with MySQL. At least, you will find the most resources online to help you on your journey.